# how to take value return by ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php

i want to draw google chart from data (ajax call)

```
var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {selValue1 : 1,selValue2 : 1} ,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
                }).responseText;
        //create our data table out of json data loaded from server
        console.log(jsonPieChartData);
```

this is the ajax.php file that return the value

```
function interncompany(){

global $DB;

//query by experience total post
$sql = 'SELECT lc.id, count(ljj.job_id) as count, lc.companyname FROM {local_jobs_job} ljj INNER JOIN {local_companydetail} lc ON ljj.job_company_userid = lc.userid  where ljj.job_type = 1 group by lc.companyname';


//get the query into record
$data = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

//put the query into array
$rows = array();

$rows = array_map(function($item) {
return (object) ['c' => [
    (object) ['v' => $item->companyname, 'f' => null],
    (object) ['v' => intval($item->count), 'f' => null]
]];
}, array_values($data));


$cols = [
(object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'LABEL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'string'],
(object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'TOTAL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'number'],
];

$returndata = new stdClass;
$returndata->cols = $cols;
$returndata->rows = $rows;

echo json_encode($returndata);

}
```

the data is selected dynamically using select box

```
if ($select1 == '1') {
    
     if ($select2 == '1') {

               jobcompany();

                }
     
     if ($select2 == '2') {
                
                joblocation();
                }
 
      if ($select2 == '3') {
                jobcategory();
        }

      
      if ($select2 == '4') {
                jobsalary();
        }

      if ($select2 == '5') {
                jobexperience();
        }


        if ($select2 == '6') {
                joblevel();
        }

 }

 elseif ($select1 == '2') {

    if ($select2 == '1') {

                interncompany();

                }
     
     if ($select2 == '2') {
                internlocation();
                }
 
      if ($select2 == '3') {
                interncategory();
        }

      
      if ($select2 == '4') {
                internsalary();
        }

      if ($select2 == '5') {
                internexperience();
        }


        if ($select2 == '6') {
                internlevel();
        }
  }
```

my question: how i want to create a function to take the data dynamically and insert the result in data:{} so that the data return to the php file so that can be read by the ajax call to draw the chart.

right now it returns nothing. i need to hardcoded inside data: {} in ajax to draw the chart.

the data dynamically select by this:

```
  // get the select value
            $(document).ready(function() {
            // for post-filter
                $('#post-filter').on('change',function(){
                var select1 = $(this).val();  // Post filter value
                var select2 = $("#field-filter").val(); // Field Filter value
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax.php',
                        data: {selValue1 : select1,selValue2 :select2 },
                        success: function(result){
                           console.log(result); 
                        }
                    });
            });



             //  field filter value.
                 $('#field-filter').on('change',function(){
                    
                    var select2 = $(this).val();  // Field filter value
                    var select1 = $("#post-filter").val(); // post Filter value
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'ajax.php',
                            data: {selValue1 : select1,selValue2 :select2 },
                            success: function(result){
                               console.log(result);  
                            }
                        });
                     });        
            });
```

this is the result when clicked the select box...only the result is not return to the ajax. what to fill inside data: {} to get the result into the drawitem function ajax call?

[image]

the error when insert the header

[image]

the result data appear but got error and the chart is not there.

Comment: `the data is selected dynamically using select box` - what is this code? where does it sit in relation to the rest of the code?

Comment: `console.log(jsonPieChartData);` what is the output of this? also, `async: false` - synchronous XMLHttpRequest on main thread is deprecated - this may eventually fail, you'll need to learn how to do things asynchronously

Comment: the console log output is null if i don't set the data:{} hardcode inside.

Comment: can i use this way to get the data:  function datareturn(){
   $.get( "ajax.php", function( data ) {
     $( "body" )
       .append( data.cols )
       .append( data.rows ); 
   }, "json" );
  }

Comment: var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
     url: "ajax.php",
     data: {datareturn} ,
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
     }).responseText;

Comment: no idea, because what the heck is `function datareturn` in relation to the code you posted? note: I refuse to read code in comments when you could put the code in the question :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below method? I have shown the example for field-filter which you can replicate for post-filter if it works

```
var dataVars = {};
dataVars['selValue1'] = $("#post-filter").val();  // Post filter value
dataVars['selValue2'] = $("#field-filter").val(); // Field Filter value


var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataVars) ,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
                }).responseText;
}
```

Also ensure content-type header is set to JSON in php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: where should I insert the header? when i put it got error

Comment: you should add header function in the PHP file

Comment: Do you get the error only when you add the header ?  Can you post a working example on plunker

Comment: the error appear when i do changes in the data:{} value inside. if i put header or not, it still appear.

Comment: I have updated my answer .. var select1 = $(this).val();    ....$(this) is referring to the DOM window and not your element. You need to refer the element and get the value like this $("#post-filter").val() ... same for the field-filter as well.... can you please check if this corrects the error?

Comment: thanks @Ashish, the error eliminated. however, the chart still cannot appear. it still doesn't fetch the data to the chart.

Comment: Sorry you need to debug and provide the piece of code that is not working. It is not possible to provide an answer with the information that has been provided

Comment: i just accept your answer..the charts can display now, after i do some modification on your answer..thanks. however, the charts doesn't display automatically with the select box, i need to refresh the page then the chart appear according to the select box value. i  just post another question here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045996/how-to-display-chart-automatically-when-choose-select-box

Comment: i asked here but been deleted and asked to ask another question regarding that